# Do right angles occur in Nature?

Tags: nature

... apart from crystal structures. Everything else seems to tend towards spherical symmetry. This is also excluding arbitrary coordinate systems.

Comment: The $p_x$, $p_y$ and $p_z$ atomic orbitals are at 90 degrees to each other.

Comment: The magnetic field is set up perpendicular to an electric field from a moving charge. Magnetic force acts perpendicularly to the direction of motion of a charge. Acceleration and net force in a circular orbit is towards the circular center perpendicular to the orbit.

Comment: When there is an oblique elastic collision between two bodies of the same mass (one being at rest), they move perpendicular to each other after it occurs.

Comment: [Centripetal force](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centripetal_force) acts at a right angle to the axis of rotation, at a right angle to the direction of motion. This question seems a bit whimsical.